# How can I get the number of affected rows after executing a ClientDataSet command?

Tags: c++builder

I'm using a `TClientDataSet` to insert/update a few rows in a Microsoft Access 2003 database table. I use code like this:

```
clientdataset->CommandText = "UPDATE TABLE1 SET ID=ID+1 WHERE ID=10";
clientdataset->Execute();
```

This ClientDataSet is connected to a `TADOQuery` through a `TDatasetProvider`.
The options of this DatasetProvider contain `poAllowCommandText`.

Is there a way to know how many rows were actually affected after executing the command?

Comment: I never understood the use of `TClientDataSet`.  Why not just execute the `UPDATE` query using the `TADOQuery` directly? It has a [`RowsAffected`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOQuery.RowsAffected) property.

Comment: One of the most important uses of TClientDataSet is in Multi-Tier Applications where you put it in a client data module wheras database conponents exist in anothe data-module.https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28876